Are Diagrams with equal source equivalent if their limits are?
Let $d_{1}:I\to Cat_{\infty}$ and $d_{2}:I\to Cat_{\infty}$ be two diagrams with the same source and with equivalent limits: there exists an equivalence of $\infty$-categories $lim d_{1}\simeq lim d_{2}$. My question is the following: is it true that $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$ are equivalent as diagrams?
Where by equivalent as diagram I mean that they are equivalent objects in the $\infty$-category $Fun(I,Cat_{\infty})$, i.e. levelwise equivalent.
I will be grateful for every comment; also comment in the ordinary categorical setting.

Suppose $I$ has an initial object. Then the limit of any functor from $I$ is given by evaluating the functor at the initial object. It is now easy to come up with counterexamples to your question by taking two functors $d_1$ and $d_2$ that take the same value on the initial object, but nonisomorphic values on the other objects.

Thanks for the answer. Do you know such a situation where the answer to my question is yes?  For example, I'm interested in the limit that appears in the answer in: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4803810/mapping-space-of-the-infinity-category-of-left-modules.

varkor gave you the paradigmatic counterexample: if all categories had an initial object, all limits would be evaluations at it -and to some extent, up to precomposing with $I\to I^\lhd$, they are. This is to say, whatever constraint puts you into the situation where you can infer a "global" equivalence ($d\cong d'$) from a "local" one (they have isomorphic limits) will be unnatural and too restrictive.

@MatteoDoni In the case you linked, you can for instance find a counterexample by finding abelian groups $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ with an abstract bijection $\mathrm{Ab}(A,B)\cong\mathrm{Ab}(C,D)$ but without a bijection $\mathrm{Set}(A,B)\cong\mathrm{Set}(C,D)$. At the very least, you should ask for your equivalence on limits to actually be induced by a natural transformation of your diagrams (after which you ask if this natural transformation specifically is an equivalence), but even then, as noted by fosco, the answer is pretty much always no, because limits do not see enough of the diagram.
